# Zend Form Element Decorator

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to prepend the label of checkbox element through decorator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->getElement('elementId')->addDecorator('Label'); ?
```

You can choose the placement as well:

```
$this->getElement('elementId')->addDecorator('Label', array('placement' => 'APPEND'))
```

Or do it through a general decorator setting:

```
'decorators' => array(
array('ViewHelper'),
array('Label', array('placement' => 'APPEND'))
```

)

Actually all information is available at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html